# Can CompactDecimalFormat somehow be used to format currency values?

Tags: java, internationalization, formatting, icu

I'm trying to use ICU4J's CompactDecimalFormat to format values like "12345.67" into "$12K".  I can't seem to see how to include the currency in the formatting:

```
CompactDecimalFormat cdFormat =
   CompactDecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.US, CompactStyle.SHORT);
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.US);
CurrencyAmount amount = new CurrencyAmount(12345.67, currency);
System.out.println(cdFormat.format(amount));
```

This results in a printout of

```
12K
```

How can I get it to take account of the currency and output "$12K" instead (and other locale + currency appropriate compact values in other locales and currencies)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use currency.getSymbol ().

Comment: Obviously I can do that.  But how can I get a formatter that will do this automatically, put the symbol or currency code in the right place for a given locale + currency combination?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in order to print the currency prefix, we can use NumberFormat:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);        
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.US);
CurrencyAmount amount = new CurrencyAmount(12345.67, currency);
System.out.println(numberFormat.format(amount));
```

This prints $12,345.67.

However, we loose the compact formatting here. So I had no choice but diving into the source code of ICU4J (52.1). After debugging, it turns out that the CompactDecimalFormat.java is based on NumberFormat but it is used as follows:

```
lig:145    DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
```

In addition, there is a commented TODO block of code there for fixing currency formatting. So I conclude that the last release of the library does not support compact currency formatting off-the-shelf.

I pushed further and I tried a simple patch to the CompactDecimalFormat.java file. I added the following methods:

```
public static CompactDecimalFormat getInstance(Locale locale, CompactStyle style, int formatNumberStyle) {
    return new CompactDecimalFormat(ULocale.forLocale(locale), style,formatNumberStyle);
}    
CompactDecimalFormat(ULocale locale, CompactStyle style,int numberFormatStyle) {
    this.pluralRules = PluralRules.forLocale(locale);
    DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(locale,numberFormatStyle);
    CompactDecimalDataCache.Data data = getData(locale, style);
    this.units = data.units;
    this.divisor = data.divisors;
    pluralToCurrencyAffixes = null;
    finishInit(style, format.toPattern(), format.getDecimalFormatSymbols());
}
```

Then I changed your code as follows:

```
    CompactDecimalFormat cdFormat = CompactDecimalFormat.getInstance(
            Locale.US, CompactStyle.SHORT,NumberFormat.CURRENCYSTYLE);
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.US);
    CurrencyAmount amount = new CurrencyAmount(12345.67, currency);
    System.out.println(cdFormat.format(amount));
```

and I could finally see the expected: $12K.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: file a bug? submit a patch?

Comment: Good hack.  But I cannot modify the library

Comment: @jlarson: no need to modify the library's jar. Just copy the modified CompactDecimalFormat in your sources preserving the package location and make sure it is loaded first by the classloader. Of course this is a workaround and I agree with Steven that something should be done directly with the developers. Feel free to submit the changes or have their feedback on them.

Comment: @GuyBouallet Right. (and, I am one of the ICU developers)